# Executable Jar: Could not load main (but main is in ANT xml)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

When I run my jar file via terminal I have no issues. However, when I put it on my client's computer it gave me the following error (when I tried it through terminal:

```
Error: could not find or load main class base.Main.

Caused by: NoClassDefFoundErrors javafx/application/Application
```

Normally I'd assume Main wasn't included. However, I exported the ANT XML as well (included below) and base.Main is where my main should be. I'm also confused because I can run the executable jar through the terminal on my machine with no issues.

I'm using the export runnable jar feature in STS. I've tried exporting multiple times. I've tried changing export settings (cycling through the options). I've verified my client had a valid JDK even though I doubt that would be the issue.

*I've spent two hours searching through answers. While I'm sure there are similar questions out there, I have not yet found when that exactly matches the issue I'm having. If you've seen one feel free to post it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for 
Project BLIS with Jar-in-Jar Loader">
<!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR file Export 
Wizard-->
<!--ANT 1.7 is required-->
<!--define folder properties-->
<property name="dir.buildfile" value="."/>
<property name="dir.workspace" value="${dir.buildfile}"/>
<property name="dir.jarfile" value="/Users/me/Documents"/>
<target name="create_run_jar">
    <jar destfile="${dir.jarfile}/BLIS.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class"            
value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"/>
            <attribute name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="base.Main"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./ spring-jdbc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar spring-jdbc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.13.jar joda-time-2.10.1.jar"/>
            </manifest>
            <zipfileset src="jar-in-jar-loader.zip"/>
            <fileset dir="${dir.workspace}/BLIS/bin"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

I know that expecting things to "just work" is unrealistic. The problem is I'm not sure where I messed up. Is it because Main-Class is the resource loader instead of base.Main? I haven't used this exporter before, but I assume it "loads the resource" before checking if main exists.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be mainly due to the unavailability of javafx.application.Application class in the classpath in the client's computer even though it is there in your machine.

Oracle by default contains the javafx, but OpenJDK does not. If it is the OpenJDK, then you will need to separately install openjfx.

Better check Java version in both machines and compare.

Hope this will help you in resolving your issue.